# std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>> is not working in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20

It seems that C++20 standard has added [support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) for `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>`. But when I write a code like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

struct A{
};

int main() {
        std::cout << std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<A>>{}.is_lock_free();
}
```

I get an error that `shared_ptr<>` is not *trivially copyable* which is true. I know being *trivially copyable* is a requirement for `std::atmoic<>` data type, but I thought that this specialization should solve this problem.

Am I missing something or Clang and GCC has not added support for this specialization yet?

Comment: You need to have C++20 enabled in the compiler options and you need to ensure thatbthe version of Clang/GCC has already implemented this feature. Clang seems to be upgrading its C++ features rather slowly.

Comment: @ALX23z I have tried this on clang 12 and gcc 11.1 with -std=c++20 on godbolt and both gives same error.

Comment: According to [this table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features) Atomic std::shared_ptr and std::weak_ptr are supported only by MSVC 19.27*

Comment: @MarekR Oh...I have never seen this page in cpp ref. Thanks for the link. a very useful one.

Comment: People these days are so impatient - we used to be happy if the number of years of waiting for a standards-compliant compiler was a single digit ;-)

Comment: It's not mentioned on the [GCC C++ Standards Support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) table, which is consistent. with that.

Comment: @molbdnilo I wonder about such impatience as well. I'm glad if I can establish a recent standard in production in the same decade... (And, when I successfully did it's about to become old fashioned.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, I don't think it's impatience. Many languages have a reference compiler that the language evolution is inextricably tied to, worked on by the same corporation in charge of the language. When a new version of the language is official, the reference compiler has support for it already. C and C++ seem to be the primary exceptions to this, with multiple independent implementations separate from one "governing" body. Even when something like C++20 isn't fully ratified yet (see previous similar questions here), this whole situation adds some confusion to those not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Marek R in the comments, most compilers still don't support this feature of C++20. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features for a table of current compiler support.